# Regex to match asterisk only if some text is present in between

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I have a regex pattern that detects the whole pattern, that is, asterisks along with the text in between.

Pattern: `(\*|__)(.*?)\1`

I want it to only match the asterisks, when the words are present in between.
Example:

```
*This is one* This is some other text *New word* Another text another* and there is some more text
```

- Asterisks of `This is one` should be detected;
- Asterisks of `New word` should be detected;
- Last asterisk shouldn't be detected, as it doesn't have any closing one.

I tried several ways, but couldn't find a way, in which the middle words are not detected and only the asterisk.

Programming Language:
Typescript (Angular)

Example 2:

```
*Project Name:* This is some other text *New word* Another text another and there is some more text
```

Comment: I think you can use `\*\b.*?\b\*` or `(\*|__)\b(.*?)\b\1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want asterisks to be detected only and not the words in between. My regex is doing exactly the same as yours

Comment: No, this is not a good idea. What are you going to do with them?

Comment: I want to replace them to ITALIC word

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It won't be possible?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/PdzmLX/1 - use the pattern as above and replace with `<ITALIC>$2<ITALIC>` or whatever with `$2` (or `\1`) in between.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Just a small correction: I meant "`$2` (or `\2`) in between", not "`$2` (or `\1`) in between".

Comment: When you say "I have tried several ways", show us what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Typescript (Angular)

Comment: See Wiktor's comment as it is correct. If you're not familiar with capture groups then get familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks. Trying @WiktorStribiżew 's solution

Comment: Also, regex101 has a code generator button so switch the language to Javascript and use the code generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/(\*|__)(?!\s)(.+?)(?<!\s)\1/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PdzmLX/4). Since you want to actually enclose `*` with tags, you may use the `<i>$2</i>` replacement pattern where `$2` is a backreference to the Group 2 value.

*Details*:

- `(\*|__)` - Group 1: `*` or `__`
- `(?!\s)` - no whitespace is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `(.+?)` - Group 2: any *one* or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?<!\s)` - no whitespace is allowed immediately on the left of the current location
- `\1` - the same value as in Group 1 (`*` or `__`).

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
let text = '*This is one* This is some other text *New word* Another text another* and there is some more text **';
text = text.replace(/(\*|__)(?!\s)(.+?)(?<!\s)\1/g, '<i>$2</i>');
console.log(text);
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there is any special character in between, like colon, semi-colon, apostrophe etc. Can it work with them too?

Comment: @MoannaTabala There can be anything but line break in between, see https://regex101.com/r/PdzmLX/3

Comment: If you try Example 2 present in the question, the regex breaks. It doesn't work as expected (when colon or any other special character comes in between)

Comment: @MoannaTabala Then try whitespace boundaries, `/(\*|__)(?!\s)(.*?)(?<!\s)\1/g`

Comment: In this way, it detects **, which is not correct.

Comment: @MoannaTabala Then require at least one char, `/(\*|__)(?!\s)(.+?)(?<!\s)\1/g`